# How to ask Python to show the lazy evaluation figures of <0x...>?

Tags: python

I tried to use the map function in Python, and got the lazy evaluation figures of 0x000002131F50ECC0 as an output. How can I ask Python to calculate the value instead of giving me an address?

Thanks in advance!

Code:-

```
A = [1, 2]
B = [3, 4]
min_value = map(min, A, B)
print(min_value)
```

Result:-

```
<map object at 0x000002131F50ECC0>
```

Comment: ... iterate over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ask the result as a list - 
the list constructor will consume the items in the map iterable:

```
min_value = list(map(min, A, B))
```

Comment: Got it. Many thanks!